# Work with setsid to open a session and close it correctly

Tags: shell-script, process, kill, process-groups

I would like to create the following script:

-- run a python script with setsid

-- python may or may not fail with exception

-- check if all of the group processes were terminated correctly

-- if not, kill the remaining processes

How can I do that?